# Can I install SQL Server Agent, but no database instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

Can one install Microsoft's SQL Server Agent, without a database instance?

(The aim is to reduce traffic to the database. I would like to put the server agent to an other server.)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: No...............................BUT if you think this is the botteneck, then something might be seriously wrong with your setup....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server Agent needs to store it's data (jobs etc) in the MSDB database. So you will need one.

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL Agent really is causing such a massive amount of I/O that it's use of MSDB is slowing down overall server performance (which I doubt is the case, but everything is possible if you try hard enough), then you have the option to move the MSDB data files to a separate disk. (Not just a separate logical drive on the same disk, but a separate disk entirely).

I expect there are many other performance improvements possible before you get to that point though. Moving TempDB to another physical disk would be a good start point.

Answer (score 0):

My question is similar.  How can I make my "instance" the default instance, so I do not have to qualify my sql server with the instance name.  Although, this is not the exact same question, I was brought here looking for an answer and others might be as well.  This solution allows you to still have multiple instances, yet define the default instance.

To do this you need to change the TCPIP dynamic port of your instance to the default 1433 port value.  Details on this simple procedure using the SQL Server Configuration Manager can be found here:

https://kohera.be/blog/sql-server/make-named-instance-look-like-default-instance/